# angularfire2: Difference between Retrieving data as lists & Retrieving data as objects

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I'am new to angularfire2, the only difference I see from the two is in when ***Retrieving data as lists***

[image]

you can query items, on the other hand ***Retrieving data as objects*** you cannot query.

Most of the snippets / sample projects I found on github related to angularfire2 uses **lists** and not **objects**, Really confused between these two. How to choose between **lists** and **objects** and what are the scenarios / use cases in which I should use **objects** rather than **lists** or it is only as simple as if I need to query something I use **lists**.

Comment: Lists are to get a set of objects from the database, that's why you have the option to use filters on it. 
For example if you want to get all the users from your database, you chhose a list and you can select to retrieve the last 20

On the other hand we use usually objects to get for example the reference object for a single user.

Comment: can i have some more information to know more details about lists and object